# adding angular animation to bootstrap dropdown

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to add animations to the opening and closing of a dropdown in my angular app. So far I can get open animations working on the dropdown, but nothing for close animations.

I took the navbar code straight from the bootstrap example and added it to my page with some minor modifications. The relevant part of the navbar is this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li ng-if="isAuthenticated()" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ authenticatedUser.displayName }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li ng-if="menuItem.show()" ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems" ng-class="{active: menuItem.active, disabled: menuItem.disabled}">
        <a ui-sref="{{ menuItem.state }}({{ menuItem.stateParams }})">{{ menuItem.heading }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm also using angular bootstrap so the line:

```
<li ng-if="isAuthenticated()" class="dropdown">
```

triggers angular's own Dropdown directive.

I noticed by simply adding a class to the inner <ul class="dropdown-menu" ...> element I could get a nice open animation.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu my-cool-opening-animation" role="menu">
```

2 questions:

1. Is this the correct 'angular' way to add the animation?
2. The animation works when the dropdown opens, but I can't get any animation when the dropdown closes, how do you do this?

[This issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1465) looks very similar to what I'm seeing and the [fix for the issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/e8d5fefcff794fce28c16c638d9f7baa624c7809) seem to be very closely related to what I want. But I don't really understand how to apply it to get animations on the dropdown close.

As a side note, but possibly relevant is I'd like to use/am using the [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) package as a base for my css animations.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced out with the same issue and spent weeks trying to make two-way fade animation I came up with tricky CSS-solution. Almost done, I've took a look at Fade animation in Angular-UI Modal and what I have found:

```
<div class="modal fade in" ng-class="{in: animate}">modal content</div>
```

After checked out the issue [#1465](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1465) and made a deeper look at Angular Docs (addClass/removeClass methods) I transferred this to Angular-UI Dropdown and what I've got so far:
http://plnkr.co/edit/KO41KkAFnCog3Vfl08Uf?p=preview

Here is the last version of my CSS:

```
.dropdown.ng-animate-start {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.open-add > .dropdown-menu,
.open-remove > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block !important;
}

.open-add > .dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
}

.open-add.open-add-active > .dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 1;
}

.open-remove > .dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
}

.open-remove.open-remove-active > .dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Hope it helps to save your time.