# Angular UI Bootstrap dropdown transition

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Total rookie to both Stack Overflow & AngularJS here. I'm trying to add a fade-in animation to my dropdown (from UI Bootstrap's dropdown directive) but to no avail.

This is very similar to this question:
[Bootstrap 3 dropdown transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876195/bootstrap-3-dropdown-transition)
, but I'm wondering if there's an Angular (non-jQuery) way to this?

Excited to be asking my first ever question on here.

Here's the code I'm using (which is pulled from UI Bootstrap's default Dropdown):

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
      Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/CmAZv4DTeda4X0bnkQwQ

Comment: can you provide us some code or fiddle of your problem ..??

Comment: Please, check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776433/adding-angular-animation-to-bootstrap-dropdown/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated** to handle fadein/out transition.

Here's a pure CSS implementation. Keep in mind, CSS3 animations are not supported in older browsers (< IE10). The following is how you would apply the CSS3 animations to bootstrap's dropdown.

CSS transitions are performed when the target property (or properties) changes value. Here's an MDN article about using them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/bFj6NkfrVk0qJbG3gwFx?p=preview

**CSS**

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease, visibility 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease, visibility 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms ease, visibility 500ms ease;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease, visibility 500ms ease;
}
```

Without `display: block`, these transitions won't work. Using the `visibility` property will maintain the same effect. I had another working example without `visibility`; however, it required you to maintain the `z-index` which I didn't think would be better.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Just tried achieving the opposite so that it will fade out (tried applying the 'fadeout' to .dropdown-menu) but I guess it doesn't work that way huh.

Comment: With the other approach, it's not as straightforward. Since you want fadein and fadeout, I changed the answer to use CSS transition rather than CSS animation. It's much cleaner IMO.

Comment: That worked a charm! Totally appreciate you explaining the mechanics behind it too.

Comment: During menu hide animation, menu moved a little bit to the right.

I had to add `.show > .dropdown-menu { margin-right: -2px; }`

Comment: Your solution is almost there but will inevitably cause scrollbars to show when you have long text within one that sits near the viewports overflow edge.  This is due to you setting `display:block` on `.dropdown-menu` which causes it to still take up space even though its visibility is hidden.  See how you can fix that in my fork: https://plnkr.co/edit/FV2KGeQcynG7QpBe